# Is it possible to decrypt a single isolated dm-crypt sector (perhaps using OpenSSL)?

Tags: openssl, dm-crypt

Given full knowledge of the parameters required to open a `dm-crypt` volume, is it possible to decrypt a single sector taken from such a volume ?

Assume that the original volume is not available but the sector number is known?

For example, the following volume mounted with `cryptsetup`:

```
$ dmsetup --showkey table myvolume
0 104857600 crypt aes-xts-plain64 95264...aacae 0 254:9 0
```

Say I had used `dd` to extract sector 125 from the raw volume:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda1 of=raw.sector bs=512 skip=125 count=1
```

And I know from the output above that the cipher is `aes-xts-plain64` and the 256-bit key is `95264...aacae` (the key example is abbreviated here).

Could I decrypt that stand-alone (say with `openssl`) ?

---

Something like this perhaps...

```
$ openssl enc -d -in raw.sector -aes-128-xts -K 95264...aacae -iv 7D -out plain.sector
```

The cipher is 128 bit because the given 256-bit key is [bisected](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101995/explanation-of-the-xts-encryption-mode) by XTS mode. The initialisation vector is `0x7D` because that is the sector number 125. However, I have failed to get beyond the first step because it would appear that OpenSSL does not support XTS (`openssl enc -ciphers`):

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/enc.c#L267:

```
if (cipher && (EVP_CIPHER_mode(cipher) == EVP_CIPH_XTS_MODE)) {
    BIO_printf(bio_err, "%s XTS ciphers not supported\n", prog);
    goto end;
}
```

(I have **OpenSSL 1.1.0f** of 25 May 2017)

---

I also tried an older OpenSSL (1.0.2f) which, although `openssl enc -ciphers` listed it, using the xts cipher `-aes-128-xts` resulted in an error message:

```
Ciphers in XTS mode are not supported by the enc utility
```

Comment: So I guess "make a loop device, decrypt with dmsetup" is not the answer you are looking for here?

Comment: Hi, this was something I was investigating ages ago. If I recall correctly, when I said "Assume that the original volume is not available" I meant that there is a sector available, not a volume that can be decrypted wuth dmsetup.

Comment: Yeah, so you could make a volume with losetup for this sector; it's easy, only downside is that it requires root permissions to set up a virtual block device in kernel, vs. doing it in userspace. (I do not know how to decrypt it with openssl, sorry.)